# Is it possible to pre-populate a form from an ad unit?

Tags: html, forms, iframe, flash, ads

This is likely a question I know the answer to but from a logistical point of view I want to just make sure. A client has asked if it is possible to have an ad unit that will contain a few form fields. If a customer fills in part of these details and then hits "submit" they will be taken to the actual form whereby the data that they entered previously will be pre-populated.

Programatically I believe this is possible (using an iframe?) but as this is going to be coming from an ad unit (more specifically a SWF file) I want to know if this is going to be possible. Could it be done using HTML5?

I know this isn't much information but at the moment it's all the info I have - I will try and update the question with more when I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `externalInterface`:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

var playerType:String = ExternalInterface.call("function(){return Capabilities.playerType}")
```

to do this, as in the following examples:

- [JavaScript and ActionScript Converse](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/javascript-and-actionscript-converse-introduction-to-externalinterface/)
- [Flash and JavaScript can Interact](http://www.codeweblog.com/flash-and-javascript-can-interact-externalinterface-class/)
- [Flex and JavaScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_javascript.html)